# Bootstrap 2.3 - unwanted vertical space between div rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3 and Foundation 5 and both are loaded on the page. There are no Firebug errors. Here's the HTML that is rendered and a screenshot. Why is there so much vertical space between the div rows?

HTML:

```
   <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span3 offset2"><span id="makemeboldlbl" class="label label-warning">Genre</span></div>
           <div class="span3"><span id="makemeboldlbl" class="label label-warning">Manager</span></div>
           <div class="span3"><span id="makemeboldlbl" class="label label-warning">ts_update</span></div>
           <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class='row-fluid'>
   <div class='span3 offset2'><a id='genre1' data-name='genre' data-type='text' data-pk='1' data-url='/updateGenre' data-title='Enter Genre'>American</a></div>
   <div class='span3'>jborn</div>
   <div class='span3'>0000-00-00 00:00:00</div>
   <div class='span1'><img src='./images/delete.png' id='delete_1' height='25' width='25' title='Remove' /></div>
   <div class='span2'>&nbsp</div>
</div>
<div class='row-fluid'>
   <div class='span3 offset2'><a id='genre2' data-name='genre' data-type='text' data-pk='2' data-url='/updateGenre' data-title='Enter Genre'>Asian</a></div>
   <div class='span3'>jborn</div>
   <div class='span3'>0000-00-00 00:00:00</div>
   <div class='span1'><img src='./images/delete.png' id='delete_2' height='25' width='25' title='Remove' /></div>
   <div class='span2'>&nbsp</div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Here's updated HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12 text-center"  id="genres">
   <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span2"><span id="makemeboldlbl" class="label label-warning">Genre</span></div>
           <div class="span2"><span id="makemeboldlbl" class="label label-warning">Manager</span></div>
           <div class="span3"><span id="makemeboldlbl" class="label label-warning">ts_update</span></div>
           <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <? echo $data ?>
</div></div>
```

Why is it not centering the rows while it's centering the header and Add New form?

[image: new problem: centering]

Answer (score 0):

try changing the span3 into span2

Comment: everywhere there's a span3 or a specific instance?

Comment: im not completely sure but i think that and entire row is composed of 12 "spans". If you decrease the size of the span's number it should decrease the size. That should reduce the white space.

Comment: While this is a very short and possibly incorrect answer, it is an attempt to answer the question and should not be deleted IMHO.

Comment: I made the changes you recommended, including removing the offsets.  But I'm having trouble centering the pages content and have updated the post.  Help!